# Convert javascript class to flash

Tags: javascript, actionscript, flash

Is there a way to convert a javascript class to flash and use it same way as the original one.

Like:

```
  var MyClass = function() {

    var exports = {};
    var message = exports.message = function message(msg)
       alert(msg);
    };

    return exports;
  };
  var theClass = new MyClass();
  theClass.message("Alert this message");
```

This class converted in flash (actionscript) and load the .swf movie:

```
  <object id="myClass" ....... 
  <script type="text/javascript">
      theFlashObject.message("Alert this message");
      // This will fire the function message in the class and will popup the alert
  </script>
```

Hope it makes sense.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to convert JavaScript to flash.

There are two things you may with to try though. You can include an **IFrame** inside of flash from which you can render HTML content (though this may not be recommended depending on your purpose). You can also use the **ExternalInterface** class to call JavaScript methods from flash.

Answer (score 0):

Check Haxe.org

Haxe is an open source toolkit based on a modern, high level, strictly typed programming language, a cross-compiler, a complete cross-platform standard library and ways to access each platform's native capabilities.

Comment: Although the answer may be helpful at some point, it is generally recommended to provide some context, preferrably in the form of example code. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer